# xna, .net, c#, saving/serializing : Folder structure. Does this plan make sense?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xna, directory

I'm just tackling serializing / deserializing for my XNA game.

Its a roguelike with procedurally generated levels.

I'm using a binary serializer.

My plan is to use have a SAVES folder with a folder structure within it with all the data.
This way it will be easy to copy and backup your saves.

Heres my plan.. I just want to check that his plan is ok and not crazy/terrible before I start implementing it..

Heres the folder structure I'm planning on using...

```
gamefolder\saves\save1\savedata.bin
                       levlel1.bin
                       level2.bin
                       level3.bin

                 save2\savedata.bin
                        level1.bin
                        level2.bin
                        level3.bin
                        level4.bin

                 \save3\savedata.bin
                        level1.bin
                        level2.bin
```

"saves" will contain a .bin file with save data for the whole game like graphics settings.

each save folder (save1, save2 save3 etc.) will contain a .bin file for that particular savegame. playername, where they are etc. also there wil be a .bin file for each level they have played thus far which records the level generated and its contents.
This way I will only have one levels data in memory at a time and will serialise/deserialse when you go to a different level.

My main concern is that reading / writing folders from a directory structure like this might be messy and may not work on xbox (Though Im not really concerned about xbox atm. I can cross that bridge when I come to it)

Comment: Why not just save all saves into one directory, then deserialize them when you want to load your game? It shouldn't be too terrible to deserialize and read and organize the data.

Comment: well. Id like to keep the levels seperate. because you can play forever you could generate 1000's of levels if you keep playing. + each one is a 5-6 meg .bin file when its serialised uncompressed (Im assuming it takes up about that much memory then)

Comment: Also it would be nice to let players copy specific saves themselves if they want. But I get what your saying... I could havea  "using" statement for instance.. Load up the big file and then load the pertainent save/level to memory and fire it up

Comment: If what your saying about 1000s of saves is true, transversing thought 1000 subdirectories isn't going to work well. You need to implement some sort of database. I don't know what XNA has at your fingertips but I would look into how other games store data, if those don't meet your standards, you probably will have a main game save file that holds all basic info of available saves, and a unique key for each. Then one directory of save games with file names as that unique key.

Comment: Read the main save file in to an object for display to your user. When they select the save they want use the key in the object and scan your saves directory for that key.

Comment: k, I cud have 1 directory with jus 1 file for each save.. And each save is a serialzed object that contains a list with all the levels + the other save data.. I could use a "using" statement as I mentioned in last comment so ther is only one level in memory at a time. That way players could still copy savegames manually.. Only problem is if they have explored 100 levels then save file could be 600-1000 Mb in size uncompressed. It might take a long time to deserialize it all to read one lvl. Also can you please explain why you think its good to comglomerate save data as you are suggesting? thx!

Comment: Typically games only store user/player information, thinking of games like Fable where certain events change the world my guess would be they only store data that is different than what a typical normal world would look like.  When I was looking a roster save for The Bigs the file was comprised as a text file of delimited data that was ordered in a fashion that their game could parse. We are talking hundreds of players. What about using XML to store the save data and then appending a header about the file contents. When you load your viewer to show all available saves, you just parse theheader

Comment: Then when you actually go to load the game you deserialize the entire XML, or better yet. Read in XML and then parse just the level you require.

Comment: I dont like all the folder saves because you are tightly coupling your game to follow a physical mechanism to properly load data. By placing all saves into one folder and having some way to index them allows you to make modification down the road.  Say you want to add a new level in-between two other existing levels, this breaks the chain.

Comment: xml serializer will only save public fields right? I dont want to have to go changing loads of stuff to public.. I guess the this isa technical challenge of procedurally generated games. In this game each time you enter a new level it is fully generated from scratch and thus needs to be saved

Comment: I am planning on compressing them. And Ive read the compression stream is unreliable and use dotnetzip http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/  so I could have a similar structure to above but instead of a folder for each save have a compressed archive for each.